# Prove that $col(A)=\mathbb{R^n}$ if A is an invertible $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that I need to prove that the column vectors of A forms a basis of $\mathbb{R^N}$

So if A is invertible then the column vectors of A are linearly independent because $A\mathbf{x}=0 \iff \mathbf{x}=0$ and that  there are $n$ vectors taken from $n$ columns so we have a basis.

I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: I'd say you're done. An alternative tack is to use the fact that $y=Ax$ has a solution $x$ for every $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. If you combine this with your approach, you don't have to resort to using the concept of dimension.

Answer (score 2):

As Harald's comment suggests, you can answer this without using the fact that $\Bbb R^n$ is "$n$-dimensional", or even the concept of a space's dimension.

Note that the columns of $A$ are independent if and only if $Ax = 0 \implies x = 0$.  In fact,
$$
Ax = 0 \implies A^{-1}Ax = A^{-1}0 \implies x = 0
$$
From there, we note that the columns of $A$ span the target space ($\Bbb R^n$ in this case) if and only if $Ax = b$ has a solution for every $b$ in $\Bbb R^n$.  In fact, for any $b$, we can set $x = A^{-1}b$ so that
$$
Ax = AA^{-1}b = b
$$
Thus, the columns of $A$ must be linearly independent and span $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 2):

The columns space is by definition that of all possible values of $Ax$, as $x$ varies over all column vectors of the correct size (domain space for $A$). That this is the whole (codomain) space means that $Ax=b$ has a solution for all $b$ in that codomain space. This is certainly the case when $A$ is invertible, since $x=A^{-1}b$ will do.

But if you look closely, it suffices that $A$ has a right inverse $R$ (so $AR$ is the identity on the codomain space), since taking $x=Rb$ gives $Ax=ARb=b$. For square matrices it makes no difference, but your result would still be true if $A$ had more columns than rows, and had a right inverse $L$ (whose shape is necessarily the shape of the transpose of $A$, with more rows than columns). So linear independence of the columns is really a bit beside the point here; it is true, but corresponds to an unused part of the hypothesis (having a left inverse).

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem that states that for an n-dimensional vector space $V$, if a set $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ is linearly independent, then it forms a basis for $V$. (There is no need to check for the spanning property.) In this case, by the fact that $\mathbf{A}x =0$ only has a trivial solution, the column vectors clearly form a linearly independent set. Hence, we are done.